# What is the Runtime Environment for React Application and what is the request-response flow in React application

Tags: reactjs

Till now I worked on Java based web applications and recently started working on ReactJS applications. Below questions are running in my mind and I appreciate your help in providing solutions for below questions:

1. I came to know that Babel is going to convert the ECMAScript2015+ code and the JSX code to ECMAScript2015 so that the browser will understand it. So does this translation will happen when we compile the React project using "npm"? And if it happens during the compilation, does the Babel will convert the entire code in the whole project at a time (or) will Babel converts the file which is requested by the client?
2. Once after creating and developing the React code, we are using Node software to install all the required dependent libraries which are used in our React code and also "**npm start**" command to start the react application. So here I want to know if NodeJS is the server which runs the React applications and without NodeJS we cannot run React application as a standalone?
3. When we take Java based web application, that Java application will be running in a server computer and Jboss or Websphere Application Server etc... are responsible of running the Java web application EAR project. Then when a client makes a request to any resource in the EAR, then the server will take the request and send the response as an HTML to the client.
        In the same way I want to know how this request response cycle works in React Application? For example, if the react application is running in a server computer and NodeJS has started the React Application in the sever computer, then when the client invokes the React application using the URL corresponding to the React Project, then what the server is going to send back to the client/browser? As Babel will convert the React application to the plain JavaScript (which is understandable to the Browser) and so does the server will be returning the Javascript back to the client?
4. If the server returns the Javascript code to the client/browser, will the server returns back the Javascript code of the entire React project (all files) to the client or will the server returns the Javascript version of ONLY the request file?

Answer (score 2):

React is a front-end library, which runs in the browser. Like any other frontend library (jQuery, etc), it is happy to be served by any old webserver – Apache, NGINX.

The react application will communicate with the backend in the form of REST API calls, which will only produce the dynamic data rather than the HTML.
The HTML is drawn using the JSX on the frontend (https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response.
I have updated my question and could you please help with my questions above?

Comment: There are environments in a react application example - development, production.
You will be needing Node and NPM only for a development environment where babel is responsible for transpiling the ES6-7 code to ES5 which will be on every file change. Once you are done with development, you can create a production build for react which is created using `npm build` command and then can host this production build on any old webserver – Apache, NGINX as this build only has JS, CSS and HTML files which.
The react production build is a transpiled and minified version of the application.

Comment: Thank you Aayush. So you are saying that before deploying the React code into production, we will build the code and during that build the React code will be converted to ES5 which is a JavaScript understandable by any browser. Am I correct?
       Also in Production when I hit the URL to launch the React application, does the server will send only the JavaScript file which is requested or will it send the JavaScript code of the whole React application to client browser?

Comment: Yes, you correct on the first statement.
For the second statement how the JS file will be served by the server?
The bundled JS and CSS files converted will be served statically by the host server i.e Apache or you can also host it on amazon S3, which will be kind of static serving. You won't be needing any application server to serve static files JS, CSS and HTML.
These files will be loaded on the first load whenever you hit the URL and it will work as a single page application, without any further reloads. Only API calls used in the application will request in network.

Answer (score 1):

1. The compilation happens every time you start your project (say `npm start`) or, if the project is already running, on any saved changes, it will recomplile every time as well as give you any errors found during compilation.
2. Yes, the NodeJS will be the one serving content. Technically, you can still use React as standalone. See [This tidbit in official ReactJS Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)
3. I'm not really great with technicalities behind React inner workings, so anyone competent feel free to correct me on this, but your server will serve JavaScript code to your browser already working and compiled fully so that even if the React server stops running (terminated or any other reason), you will still be able to work with most of the application since the data has been already loaded. There may be libraries/packages that allow lazy loading of components, but that depends on your usecase, I guess.
4. See my final bits in the previous point.

Hope this helped you in some way